# extjs 4.1 treestore lazy loading: The q is, does it branch?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.1

I want to achive lazy loading of tree branches in an MVC application with extjs4.1 where the braches are located on different urls. I have come quite some ways and hit quite some walls, right now it does not branch.

Here is where I fail:

```
Ext.define('OI.view.tree.Tree' ,{
    extend: 'Ext.tree.Panel',
    alias : 'widget.treepanel',
    store: 'TreeStore',
    collapsible: true,
    rootVisible: false,

    viewConfig: {
        plugins: [{
            ptype: 'treeviewdragdrop'
        }]
    },
    height: 350,
    width: 400,
    title: 'Directory Listing',

    initComponent: function() {
        this.store = Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup(this.store);
        this.store.getProxy().url = 'data/level1.json'; // <-- init loading
        this.store.load();
        this.callParent(arguments);
    },

    listeners: {
        itemclick: function(view, record) {

            console.info('ID: '+record.get('id'));
            console.info('TEXT: '+record.get('text'));
            console.info('PrimType: '+record.get('primaryType'));
            console.info(record.fields.getCount());
            console.info('JCRPATH: '+record.get('jcrPath'));

            var newBranchStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
                model: 'OI.model.Branch',
                autoLoad: true,
                proxy: {
                    type: 'ajax',
                    reader: {
                        url: 'data/'+ record.get('jcrPath') +'/level1.json', //<-- load json at the level of the url path returned by the model
                        type: 'json'
                    }
                },  
                folderSort: false
            });

            newBranchStore.load({url: 'data/'+ record.get('jcrPath') +'/level1.json',
                callback: function(){
                    console.log('loaded');
                    var mynode = newBranchStore.getNodeById('content_mytest');
                    console.info(mynode.get('id'));
                    this.store.getNodeById(record.get('id')).appendChild(mynode).expand(); // <-- this does not work
                },
                scope: this
            });
        }
    }
});
```

The first level is loaded correctly, however when I trigger a click on the node, I am getting the right json returned from the server, in this case a static json file for debugging, and I try to statically fetch a node and append it to the one that has been clicked. But it is never injected.

What I eventually want to achive is that I can append all children returned by the json file to the node that has been clicked.

Further I am a bit confused about treestores ...
Am I correct when I say that there can be only ONE treestore per tree, right? So I need to attach the new nodes to the original treestore ... I am slightly confused and could need all the pointers I can get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are way overcomplicating this, use this approach instead (basically just swap out the url of your store before it loads to the correct url):

```
Ext.define('OI.view.tree.Tree' ,{
    extend: 'Ext.tree.Panel',
    alias : 'widget.treepanel',
    store: 'TreeStore',
    collapsible: true,
    rootVisible: false,

    viewConfig: {
        plugins: [{
            ptype: 'treeviewdragdrop'
        }]
    },
    height: 350,
    width: 400,
    title: 'Directory Listing',

    initComponent: function() {
        this.store = Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup(this.store);
        this.store.getProxy().url = 'data/level1.json'; // <-- init loading
        this.store.load();
        this.callParent(arguments);
    },

    listeners: {

        beforeload: function(store, operation) {
            store.getProxy().url = 'data/'+ operation.node.get('jcrPath') +'/level1.json';
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much ... you need to change it to beforeload: function(store, operation) {  for it to work properly ...